# How to call a js function in other file with arguments in karate?

Tags: karate

I have a karate feature which needs to call a JavaScript function with arguments from js file. Not in the feature itself. Want to organise many js function in separate file and call it from a feature file. Just like creating java step definitions with cucumber.

```
Feature: Inside new
Background:
    * def result = call read(‘GetTokens.feature')
    Given url devURL
    * def at = result.access_token
    * def rt = result.refresh_token
    * def data = read('classpath:src/main/resources/GetHeaders.js', at, rt)
    * configure headers = data

Scenario Outline: new
    Given path ‘new’
    And request ‘’
    When method post
    And status 201
```

This feature calls GetHeaders.js But not able to read the arguments. Is there anything wrong with the way it's been called. Or karate framework/nashorn can't support.

```
#GetHeaders.js    
var f1 = function(at, rt){
    var head = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'token': at,
      'refresh-token': rt,
      'channel': 'online'
    }
    return head
}
```

Comment: you are trying to do something that karate does not support. karate is not cucumber and if you try to apply the same concepts here it won't work. can you please read the documentation and keep it simple: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#multiple-functions-in-one-file

Answer (score 1):

Move the js code to a function within a feature file. The function can be called using any number of arguments just like any other js or java functions. Below is the sample code incase you want any reference.

```
* def GetHeaders = 
"""
   function(at, rt){
       var head = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'token': at,
          'refresh-token': rt,
          'channel': 'online'
        }
   return head
   }
"""
* karate.log(GetHeaders('shfusdfhdskfds', 'ueworuewoew767638'))
```

Comment: * def headerObject = GetHeaders('shfusdfhdskfds', 'ueworuewoew767638')

      * karate.log("headers " + headerObject ) This prints  headers [object Object] 

      * karate.log("headers " + GetHeaders('shfusdfhdskfds', 'ueworuewoew767638')) This print the data in expected format.

Comment: what to fo incase i want to call GetHeaders only once like "callonce GetHeaders...."

Answer (score 0):

Try calling the js code in this format. It should work

```
* def data = call read('classpath:src/main/resources/GetHeaders.js@f1') {at:#(at), rt:#(rt)}
```

Answer (score -1):

karate does not support calling js methods from external files